# Insert a value If a match is found in join table

Tags: mysql, sql, icd

I have a table of ICD9 codes where several of them are not coded properly. I would like to insert "No" into a column in that table if a match can not be found in another table.

So for example, I have a code 292300 and It should be 2923. I want to have something like

`SELECT icd9, icd10 from icd9codes, GEM where icd9 = icd10;`

And if there is not a match found for the icd9 code then do an `INSERT INTO`.

Note: GEM table contains icd9 codes and their equivalent mappings for icd10.

Comment: show your db schema for the related table  please

Comment: Something like: `update table1 left join table2 on table1.col = table2.col where table2.col is null set table1.other_col = 'ZZZ'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting a new row into `icd9codes`, then this is a very simple `SELECT` query.

```
insert into icd9codes (icd9)
select icd10
from GEM;
```

That is the most literal answer to your question.  However, I suspect that what you have is existing rows in `icd9codes` and you want to update a column value on those rows, if their `icd9` value exists in `icd10` of `GEM`.

```
update icd9codes
set the_new_column = 'No'
where exists (
  select 1
  from GEM
  where icd10 = icd9codes.icd9
);
```

This says, for any row in `icd9codes` which has a corresponding value in `GEM`, set its `the_new_column` value to `No`.

Comment: you were on the money with the update command. I should have stated the question better. All I was after was to find the codes that had no match in another table so I could fix the formatting so I could map them to the newer codes. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We need your database schema, in the meantime, heres a shot in the dark.
Back up your table first.

```
UPDATE icd9codes
LEFT JOIN GEM ON
icd9codes.icd9 = GEM.icd9
SET icd9codes.icd9 = COALESCE(GEM.icd10,'No')
```